# Filter list by sublist element match

Tags: python

I have the following doubly-nested list:

```
records = [[['Jack', 'male', 1],['Jack', 'male', 2],['Jack', 'male', 3]],[['Sally', 'female', 1],['Sally', 'female', 2],['Sally', 'female', 3]]]
```

I want to filter this list according to where the 2nd element (by indexing) of the inner-most list equals 1. The result should look like this:

```
records
[[['Jack', 'male', 1]],[['Sally', 'female', 1]]]
```

I think some form of nested list comprehension with a conditional is probably what I need but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
records = [[['Jack', 'male', 1],['Jack', 'male', 2],['Jack', 'male', 3]],[['Sally', 'female', 1],['Sally', 'female', 2],['Sally', 'female', 3]]]
final_records = [[i for i in b if i[-1] == 1] for b in records]
```

Output:

```
[[['Jack', 'male', 1]], [['Sally', 'female', 1]]]
```